# Accessing E4PartWrapper's MPart in Eclipse 3.x RCP application

Tags: eclipse

I am using the ability to add an Eclipse 4.x part to an Eclipse 3.x RCP application's perspective as described in the Vogella chapter on RCP migration.  All is well, I can create an 4.x part and view it in a 3.x perspective.

I'd like to access the instantiated 4.x POJO (in my case it contains a Browser widget) and set some parameters for display (the browser URL). However when I try to probe the constructed ViewPart what I have to deal with is an E4PartWrapper object:

```
E4PartWrapper newPart = 
        window.getActivePage().
        showView(ViewEclipse4x.ID, 
                 String.valueOf(nextId), 
                 IWorkbenchPage.VIEW_ACTIVATE);
```

I can see from the code that E4PartWrapper does contain the wrapped part, but I don't see a way to access this object.

Is there an alternative to accessing the 4.x POJO underlying the constructed 3.x ViewPart?

Thank you.

Carlos S. Zamudio

Comment: Note: E4PartWrapper is an internal class so you should not be using it - just the normal ViewPart.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I can see the MPart can be found using the PartService:

EPartService partService = (EPartService) viewSite.getService(EPartService.class);
MPart part = partService.findPart(partName);